# Reading a CSV file, calculating averages and printing said averages

Tags: python

I have been assigned a task to create a quiz for primary school members. I have nailed every single task but this one.

I have to calculate the scores in the CSV file by:
• in alphabetical order with each student’s highest score for the tests
• by the highest score, highest to lowest
• by the average score, highest to lowest.

Here's the code I have so far. It doesn't seem to calculate the averages, even though I have followed the PowerPoint effectively. Everything in the PowerPoint is in the code.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import csv

results = open("Scores1.csv", "r+")
csv1 = csv.reader(results, delimiter=",")


data = []

for eachline in csv1:
    print(eachline)
    eachline[1] = int(eachline[1])
    eachline[2] = int(eachline[2])
    eachline[3] = int(eachline[3])
    highscore = max(eachline[1:4])
    eachline.append(highscore)
    average = round(sum(eachline[1:4])/3)
    eachline.append(average)
    data.append(eachline)

print(data)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\My Work\Year 11\Computing\A453 Programming Project\PythonFiles\scores.py", line 17, in <module>
    eachline[1] = int(eachline[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand the error being given to me, as everything in the CSV file looks fine.
I aren't the best at it, and would like a simple answer please so I can understand it effectively and learn from it.

Many thanks.

Comment: do you have 4 or 5 columns in your CSV file?

Comment: Hi, I have two - Name and Score

Comment: but you are accessing column 3 and 4 as well: eachline[2], eachline[3]

Comment: Should that be eachrow then? Or is it something completely different?

Comment: Just search for a good example and do something similar - there are too many wrong things in your code. There must be plenty similar questions  on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.scores = []
        self.highestscore = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<' + self.name + ', ' \
              + 'high=' + str(self.highestscore) + ', ' \
              + 'avg=' + str(self.getAverage()) + '>'

    def addScore(self, score):
        self.scores.append(score)
        self.highestscore = max(self.highestscore, score)

    def getAverage(self):
        l = len(self.scores)
        if l == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return sum(self.scores) / l

import csv

results = open("C:\Projetos\Data\Python\Scores1.csv", "r+")
csv1 = csv.reader(results, delimiter=",")


data = {}
highscore = 0

for eachline in csv1:
    #print(eachline)
    name = eachline[0]

    student = data.get(name, None)
    if student == None:
        student = Student(name)
        data[name] = student

    score = int(eachline[1])
    student.addScore(score)

students = [data[key] for key in data]

sorted_alphabetically = sorted(students, key=lambda x:x.name)
sorted_by_highest_score = sorted(students, key=lambda x:x.highestscore, reverse=True)
sorted_by_avg_score = sorted(students, key=lambda x:x.getAverage(), reverse=True)

print 'sorted_alphabetically =', sorted_alphabetically
print 'sorted_by_highest_score =', sorted_by_highest_score
print 'sorted_by_avg_score =', sorted_by_avg_score
```

Input:

```
a,3
b,4
c,5
e,4
a,2
b,5
c,6
e,9
a,1
b,3
c,2
e,4
```

Output:

```
sorted_alphabetically = [<a, high=3, avg=2>, <b, high=5, avg=4>, <c, high=6, avg=4>, <e, high=9, avg=5>]
sorted_by_highest_score = [<e, high=9, avg=5>, <c, high=6, avg=4>, <b, high=5, avg=4>, <a, high=3, avg=2>]
sorted_by_avg_score = [<e, high=9, avg=5>, <c, high=6, avg=4>, <b, high=5, avg=4>, <a, high=3, avg=2>]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll use this as an example

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the pandas libary, for example, mean and max of rows can be can be obtained like this, but your example should be more precise, can't really see the exact structure of the csv file:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("Scores1.csv")
data['mean']= data.mean(axis=1)
data['max'] = data.max(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this